# How do I express "$n$ is the smallest natural above $k \in \mathbb{R}$"?

Tags: notation

I have a real number $k > 0$ and want to find a simple mathematical formula defining $n$ as the smallest natural number above $k$. How would you write this ?

For instance:
\begin{equation}
n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ n - k \ge 0 \ \mathrm{and} \ n-k = \min_{u \in \mathbb{N}}{(f(u, k) = u-k})
\end{equation}

Comment: With above, do you mean $n \geq k$ or $n > k$?

Comment: Are you familiar with floor ($\lfloor k \rfloor$) and ceiling ($\lceil k\rceil$) functions? They may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @BartMichels I just edited my post, it was $\ge$ as you said

Comment: @Cafeinicola no I didn't know that !  How did you write it in Mathjax ?

Comment: @EmileCouzin in MathJax, there are two different symbols for each one, the left one and the right one. For floor function, \lfloor is for $\lfloor$ and \rfloor for $\rfloor$. For the ceiling function, it's the same but with \lceil and \rceil. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the ceiling function $\lceil k \rceil := \text{the smallest integer}\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{such that}\ n\geq k$ (note the non-strict inequality). The ceiling function may also be written as $k+1-\{k\} =: \lceil k \rceil$, where $\{k\}$ is the fractional part of $k$. E.g. $\{1.2456\} = 0.2456$ and $\{-3.2\} = 0.8$ (since $-3.2 = -4 + 0.8$).

Comment: The smallest integer above k would be floor(k+1). Consider say k = 3 where OP wants a result of 4.

Comment: I believe OP allows for non-strict inequality, so the smallest integer above $k=3$ is $3$.